# Cognos Static prompt values to be passed to SQL

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have a static prompt which is a single select. In that I have two values lets call it A and B. So when I select option 'A' my report pulls all data from the DB which is expected. So when user Select option 'B' the report should pull only the records whose code = 'M'. Here code is a column name in the report.

Note: For option 'A' I don't need to set any prompt in the report because it should pull all records by default.

Comment: I think you're asking how to implement a prompt filter where one choice will filter the response and the other will return all values.

The second paragraph seems to state something otherwise.  

So, basically, can you make it a bit clearer what your question is please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your parameter name is *param* and data item is named *item*.

Filter expression:

```
if (?param? = 'A')
then ([item])
else ('M')
 = [item]
```

Note:  You absolutely need to use a prompt.  The result of selecting A should be to not filter.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand, try this:

- Make the prompt a single value (i.e. B) with a use value of 'M'
- Make the HEADER TEXT for the prompt A  (so it is not an actual selection)
- Make the filter optional

if the user selects A - the prompt is NULL and the optional filter is ignored
if the user selects B - the filter [Some data item] = ?YourParm? will occur

Also, if you prefer to not have header text
you can make static values A, B and modify the optional filter to be like this:

- (?YourParm? <> 'M') OR ([Some data item] = ?YourParm?)